# How do I install Windows on a computer with Grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, data-recovery

I previously installed Ubuntu and I wanted to install windows vista via the repair disc included with the laptop. Booted up the computer with the disc in, nothing. I already set the boot order, so that is not the issue. I booted from an Ubuntu live CD and just deleted all the partitions via GParted, but still no dice. So now I basically have a computer with no operating system that cannot boot from the windows vista recovery disc, but I can boot from an Ubuntu liveCD. Grub seems to still be installed, and for some reason blocks me from booting from a recovery disc. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It seems like grub is still on the drive but it's dependencies have been deleted (when you formatted). I don't have a clue why your vista disk wont work though.

Comment: I found this question: http://superuser.com/questions/74017/why-do-i-get-a-grub-error-after-deleting-the-linux-partition which provides a fix for the grub problem, at least.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu) (*I should have a Vista iso somewhere. You potentially saved me hours.*)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might deleted windows vista recovery partition.
Usually laptops doesn't come with OS installation CD, but comes with recovery partition that you can use to reinstall windows.

Do you have windows vista installation disc?
If not then your repair disc won't help, cause there is nothing to repair, you can try to download windows vista installation ISO and then burn it to a CD or make bootable USB drive with vista installation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my stupidity.I should have a vista iso somewhere. You potentially saved me hours. Thanks!